# Matlab simulate neural network mat file in gui

Tags: neural-network, matlab-load

I have saved a neural network in .mat and I would like to simulate this file in my gui. Is it necessary to import this file into workspace then only import from workspace into gui **OR** we can load it in the gui without having to import it into workspace at first?

Thank you and your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-load-mat-files.html) in the MATLAB documentation. I quote:

The following command loads all variables from the example file durer.mat:

```
load('durer.mat')
```

To load variables into a structure array, specify an output variable for the load function:

```
durerStruct = load('durer.mat')
```

So in this way you avoid using the workspace. Another possibility is described as well:

The matfile function allows you import part of a variable, which requires less memory than loading an entire variable. For example, load the first 50 rows from variable topo in topography.mat into a variable called partOfTopo:

```
topography = matfile('topography.mat');
partOfTopo = topography.topo(1:50,:);
```